# I am getting a warning regarding an infinite update loop in a component render. What part of my code is causing this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my application I have a list of documents that I display in a table, each document has a specific type, which is specified in json file as enum values.
I can already display all the documents without any problems, but now I have tried to create an input where the user can choose from the list of enum values, and when doing so only the documents with the selected enum type will be shown in the table.
This does sorta work, but the problem is that I have somehow created an infinite update loop, which causes the application to randomly stop working.

This is the template. I am using a custom made template component, but that is not related to the issue.

```html
<template>
  <b-container>
    <div @dragover.prevent.stop @drop.prevent.stop="onDropEvent">
      <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
        <b-button-toolbar justify>
          <b-button
            :class="showCollapse ? 'collapsed' : null"
            @click="showCollapse = !showCollapse"
            variant="outline-info"
            class="flex-grow-1"
          >
            <span class="float-left">{{ folderName }}</span>
            <span class="float-right">
            {{
                search ?
                  $t('documentCountFiltered', {filtered: filteredDocuments.length, count: documents.length}) :
                  $tc('documentCount', documents.length)
              }}
          </span>
          </b-button>
          <template v-if="!inherited && mode !== 'READ_ONLY'">
            <label class="document-uploader btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary ml-2">
            <span>
              <i class="fas fa-fw fa-file-upload"></i>
              {{ $t('uploadFiles') }}
            </span>
              <input type="file" multiple @change="selectFiles">
            </label>
            <b-dropdown
              v-if="mode !== 'READ_ONLY' && mode !== 'RESTRICTED'"
              size="sm" variant="outline-primary" class="ml-2 template-dropdown" no-caret right>
              <template slot="button-content">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-file-medical"></i> {{ $t('createDocument') }}
              </template>
              <b-dropdown-header v-if="companyTemplates.length !== 0" id="dropdown-header-templates">
                {{ $t('companyTemplates') }}
              </b-dropdown-header>
              <b-dropdown-item v-if="companyTemplates.length !== 0" v-for="template of companyTemplates"
                               @click="emitWordDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template)">
                {{ template.name }} <i v-if="template.freeTextEnabled" class="fa-fw fas fa-paragraph"></i>
              </b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-divider
                v-if="companyTemplates.length !== 0 && companyFormBuilderTemplates.length > 0"></b-dropdown-divider>
              <b-dropdown-header v-if="companyFormBuilderTemplates.length > 0" id="dropdown-header-inheritedDocuments">
                {{ $t('formBuilderTemplates') }}
              </b-dropdown-header>
              <b-dropdown-item
                v-for="template of companyFormBuilderTemplates"
                @click="emitDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template)">
                {{ template.name }}
              </b-dropdown-item>

              <b-dropdown-divider
                v-if="globalTemplates.length !== 0"></b-dropdown-divider>
              <b-dropdown-header v-if="globalTemplates.length > 0" id="dropdown-header-globalDocuments">
                {{ $t('globalTemplates') }}
              </b-dropdown-header>
              <b-dropdown-item
                v-for="template of globalTemplates"
                @click="emitGlobalDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template)">
                {{ template.name }}
              </b-dropdown-item>

            </b-dropdown>
          </template>
        </b-button-toolbar>
      </b-card-header>

      <b-form-group class="mt-4">
        <w-b-form-select v-model="filteredDocumentType">

          <template>
            <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>-- {{ $t('selectDocumentByType') }} --</b-form-select-option>
          </template>

          <b-form-select-option :value="'all'">({{ $t('all') }})</b-form-select-option>

          <option v-for="documentType in availableDocumentTypes" :key="documentType" :value="documentType">
            {{ $t('model.document.types.' + documentType) }}
          </option>

        </w-b-form-select>
      </b-form-group>

      <b-collapse v-model="showCollapse">
        <common-table
          :fields="fields"
          :items="filteredDocuments"
          primary-key="id"
          sort-by="creationDateTime"
          sort-desc
        >
          <template slot="head(select)">
            <check-all-checkbox :list="filteredDocuments" @change="handleTag(documents, $event)" property="selected"/>
          </template>
          <template slot="cell(select)" slot-scope="data">
            <w-b-form-checkbox v-model="data.item.selected" v-if="data.item.selected != null"
                               @change="handleTag([data.item], $event)" data-test-id="check-box"/>
          </template>
          <template slot="cell(name)" slot-scope="data">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div style="flex: 2 0 0">
                <b-dropdown :text="data.item.name" variant="link" toggle-class="name-cell">
                  <b-dropdown-item @click="viewFile(data.item)" v-if="data.item.type != 'EMAIL'"><i
                    class="fas fa-eye"></i> {{ $t('showDocument') }}
                  </b-dropdown-item>
                  <b-dropdown-item @click="downloadFile(data.item)"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i> {{
                      $t('download')
                    }}
                  </b-dropdown-item>
                </b-dropdown>
              </div>
              <div style="flex: 1 0 0" v-if="data.item.uploading">
                <b-progress :animated="!data.item.error" striped class="h-100">
                  <b-progress-bar
                    :value="100"
                    :variant="data.item.error ? 'danger' : 'primary'"
                    :label="data.item.error ? 'Error' : 'Uploading...'"
                  />
                </b-progress>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </common-table>
      </b-collapse>
      <p-d-f-j-s-viewer ref="pdf-viewer"/>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

My script

```html
<script>
  import CheckAllCheckbox from '@/components/CheckAllCheckbox';
  import CommonTable from '@/components/common/CommonTable';
  import CommonInput from '@/components/common/CommonInput';
  import {applianceService} from '@/services/appliance';
  import PDFJSViewer from '@/components/PDFJSViewer';
  import axios from '@/config/axios';
  import {documentService} from '@/services/document';
  import documentTypes from '@/models/document/type';
  import {propertyFacilityService} from '@/services/property-facility';
  import CommonCollapsible from '@/components/common/CommonCollapsible';


  export default {
    props: {
      documents: Array,
      documentOwnerType: String,
      companyTemplates: Array,
      companyFormBuilderTemplates: Array,
      globalTemplates: Array,
      inherited: Boolean,
      startCollapsed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      mode: String,
      search: String,
      applianceId: String,
      propertyFacilityId: String,
      noteId:String
    },
    components: {
      CheckAllCheckbox,
      CommonTable,
      CommonCollapsible,
      CommonInput,
      PDFJSViewer
    },
    data() {
      return {
        documentTypes,
        showCollapse: true,
        filteredDocumentType: null

      };
    },
    computed: {
      filteredDocuments() {
        console.log(this.filteredDocumentType)
        console.log(this.documents)
        if (this.filteredDocumentType === null || this.filteredDocumentType === 'all') {
          return (this.documents ?? []).filter(document =>
            (document.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase()) ||
              this.$t(`model.document.types.${document.type}`).toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())))
        }
        else {
          return (this.documents ?? []).filter(document =>
            (document.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase()) ||
              this.$t(`model.document.types.${document.type}`).toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())) &&
            document.type === this.filteredDocumentType)
        }
      },
      folderName() {
        if (this.inherited) {
          return this.$t('sharedDocuments');
        } else if (this.documentOwnerType === 'COMPANY') {
          return this.$t('companyDocuments');
        } else {
          return this.$t('documents');
        }
      },
      availableDocumentTypes() {
        return this.documentTypes.sort((a, b) => this.getDocumentTypeText(a).localeCompare(this.getDocumentTypeText(b)));
      },
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'select',
            thStyle: 'width: 1%'
          },
          {
            key: 'name',
            label: this.$t('name'),
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'inherited',
            label: this.$t('inherited'),
            formatter: inherited => this.$t(inherited ? 'yes' : 'no'),
            sortable: true,
            hide: this.inherited
          },
          {
            key: 'sharedOnTC',
            label: this.$t('sharedOnTC'),
            formatter: sharedOnTC => this.$t(sharedOnTC ? 'yes' : 'no'),
            sortable: true,
            hide: this.sharedOnTC
          },
          {
            key: 'type',
            label: this.$t('type'),
            formatter: type => this.$t('model.document.types.' + type),
            sortable: true,
            sortByFormatted: true
          },
          {
            key: 'tags',
            label: this.$t('tags'),
            formatter: tags => tags.join(', '),
            sortable: true,
            sortByFormatted: true
          },
          {
            key: 'signed',
            label: this.$t('signed'),
            formatter: sharedOnTC => this.$t(sharedOnTC ? 'yes' : 'no'),
            sortable: true,
            sortByFormatted: true
          },
          {
            key: 'creationDateTime',
            label: this.$t('created'),
            sortable: true,
            template: {type: 'date', format: 'L LT'}
          },
          {
            key: 'changedDateTime',
            label: this.$t('changed'),
            sortable: true,
            template: {type: 'date', format: 'L LT'}
          },
          {
            key: 'actions',
            hide: this.inherited || this.mode === 'READ_ONLY',
            template: {
              type: 'actions',
              cell: [
                {
                  icon: 'fa-edit',
                  tooltip: this.$t('edit'),
                  if: this.mode !== 'RESTRICTED',
                  disabled: data => data.item.uploading || !data.item.documentTemplateId || data.item.signed,
                  action: data => this.emitDocumentEditTemplateSelectEvent(data.item)
                },
                {
                  icon: 'fa-cog',
                  tooltip: this.$t('documentSettings'),
                  disabled: data => data.item.uploading,
                  action: data => this.emitDocumentEditSelectEvent(data.item)
                },
                {
                  icon: 'fa-trash',
                  variant: 'outline-danger',
                  disabled: data => data.item.uploading,
                  action: data => this.emitDocumentDeleteSelectEvent(data.item)
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ].filter(field => !field.hide);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getDocumentTypeText(type) {
        return this.$t(`model.document.types.${type}`);
      },
      selectFiles(event) {
        this.emitFileUploadEvent(event.target.files);
        event.target.value = '';
      },
      onDropEvent(event) {
        this.emitFileUploadEvent(event.dataTransfer.files);
      },
      downloadFile(document) {
        documentService.downloadDocument(document.id)
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      },
      viewFile(document) {
        documentService.getPublicDownloadToken(document.id).then(result => {
          let fileName = `${axios.defaults.baseURL}/file/public/${result.data}/download`;

          this.$refs['pdf-viewer'].show(fileName);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      },
      emitGlobalDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template) {
        this.$emit('document-global-create-select', template);
      },
      emitDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template) {
        this.$emit('document-create-select', template);
      },
      emitWordDocumentCreateSelectEvent(template) {
        this.$emit('document-word-create-select', template);
      },
      emitDocumentEditSelectEvent(document) {
        documentService.getDocument(document.id).then(result => {
          document = result.data;
          this.$emit('document-edit-select', document);
        });
      },
      emitDocumentEditTemplateSelectEvent(document) {
        this.$emit('document-edit-template-select', document);
      },
      emitDocumentDeleteSelectEvent(document) {
        this.$emit('document-delete-select', document);
      },
      emitFileUploadEvent(files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
          this.$emit('file-upload', [...files]);
        }
      },
      handleTag(documents, selected) {
        if (this.applianceId) {
          applianceService.updateDocuments(this.applianceId, {
            documentIds: documents.map(doc => doc.id), selected: selected
          }).then(({data: documents}) => {
            documents.forEach(doc => {
              this.documents.splice(this.documents.findIndex(d => d.id === doc.id), 1,
                Object.assign(doc, {selected: selected}));
            });
          });
        }
        if (this.propertyFacilityId) {
          propertyFacilityService.updateDocuments(this.propertyFacilityId, {
            documentIds: documents.map(doc => doc.id), selected: selected
          }).then(({data: documents}) => {
            documents.forEach(doc => {
              this.documents.splice(this.documents.findIndex(d => d.id === doc.id), 1,
                Object.assign(doc, {selected: selected}));
            });
          });

        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.showCollapse = !this.startCollapsed;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, are you sure that you provided the complete code? It is badly formatted, and not easy to check. Can you please correct it?

Comment: Sure. I thought it would be more confusing if I added the complete code, but I added it now.

Comment: Could it be that some of the inner components have a watcher reacting to prop changes. For example, <check-all-checkbox> could perhaps emit a "change" event, once it recognizes its prop :list is changed.  That could lead to infinite update, since it is modifying the original array inside handler.